# Facebook user_photo permission not shown to users

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

this is my login url.

```
$FbPerm = ['email', 'user_likes', 'user_photos'];
$FbLoginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://laravel.dev/callback-facebook.php', $FbPerm);
```

when user click to login button, user_photo permissions not shown.

if I add user to developer from developers.facebook.com , there is no problem facebook asking user_photos permission.

Comment: It seems like you haven't been approved by Facebook to request that permission from users (who aren't admins/devs/testers of your app) - are you familiar with this document? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: you 're right. thank you!